# C++: Forward declaration of a class with a deleter for a unique pointer that can be repeated

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, forward-declaration, pimpl-idiom

In C++, it is possible to use forward declaration to allow pointers to an incomplete type.

```
class A;
A *p;
```

However, in some cases I want to declare a unique pointer instead, so I use

```
class A;
class A_Deleter { void operator()(A*); }
unique_ptr<A, A_Deleter> p;
```

This is adequate in many cases, but has one major disadvantage. Unlike a real forward declaration, it cannot be written twice. I.e. while this code compiles:

```
class A;
class A;
```

This one doesn't:

```
class A;
class A_Deleter { void operator()(A*); }
class A;
class A_Deleter { void operator()(A*); }
```

How would you forward declare a deleteable class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my solution.

I define a class visible through a header to everyone:

```
template <class T> class deleter { void operator()(T *x); };
```

I can then get rid of the need to declare the deleter class and can write things like this:

```
class A;
unique_ptr<A, deleter<A> > p;
```

The `deleter<T>::operator()` for each `T` can be implemented using specialization in its own `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to repeat it?

Put the declarations in a header (with proper include guards) and include it where needed.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a header specifically for the forward declaration, which also declares the deleter. Give the header the usual guards, and include that header instead of forward-declaring `A`.

But in general, I would go a different route. If I just need to declare the unique pointer, I would just forward-declare and do `unique_ptr<A>`. If I actually have a context where the unique pointer is destroyed, I would grab the full definition of `A`.

Comment: I want to be able delete A without access to its full definition, only a deleter. Also, while the header is solution is possible, it forces me to have a very short headers that specify forward declaration for just one class, which is messy imho.

Comment: Messy, or doesn't compile. Pick one.

Comment: @tohava I don't think it's so messy. I actulally do this in my projects. It puts the class very nicely in perspective - the location of the header tells you something about where the class comes from. And if you later find you need to replace `class A;` with `typedef SomethingOrOther A;`, you're in a lot less trouble when the thing's in a header.

Comment: @Angew - Good point about the typedefs. If I have several very small classes that are related I usually put them in the same header, I think it makes things clearer rather than putting each one in a separate header, java-style. I'll probably solve it your way though.